# MVC3 - What's with the caching of razor views?

Tags: caching, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

What is the official line on how to make sure a razor view is rendered as latest? At the moment it appears I am getting a cached version.

I have a view, that renders a partial and this partial renders a template.

Save, compile, iis reset:

Same old view!

Stop it now!

Let me give u an example

@Html.EditorForModel("~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Object.ascx")

Renders Object.ascx

Remove that line renders nothing (good)

Then adding 
@Html.EditorForModel("~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Huh.cshtml")

Renders Object.ascx

=Insanity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: it has to be called Object.cshtml and no other control called "Object" can live in that folder (e.g. Object.ascx).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try <kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd> in your browser? Maybe the html was cached on the client. Also if you are using the `[OutputCache]` attribute to cache it downstream this could happen.

---

UPDATE:

After you have posted your code you seem to have overriden the `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Object.ascx` default template. Then you replace this line by:

```
@Html.EditorForModel("~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Huh.cshtml")
```

but depending on the model used in `Huh.cshtml` `Object.ascx` could still be rendered for some properties.

Comment: I have only ever used ctrl+R to refresh a page since 1996

Comment: ctrl+R does not clear the browsers cache for the page, it just reloads it (possibly from cache again).  ctrl+F5 clears the cache and redownloads everything from the server.

Comment: @BobTodd, please see my UPDATE. Try deleting Object.ascx. Do you still get the old markup?